# Using composer autoload from subfolder

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have installed one package with composer by default to `./vendor/company/packagename`. When I run scripts in root folder and include `./vendor/autoload.php` all works good. But when I try run scripts from `./api/` subfolder and include `../vendor/autoload.php` I received "Class not found" errors. So installed package not found as I see.

What can I do in this situation, how can I run scripts from sub-folders in this case?

Comment: Don't run the scripts from subfolders - adjust your scripts to run from the top, possibly using the console approach - http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html

Answer (score 4):

Try to include the autloader file from the `api` subfolder this way:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is not in the way you include the file. Do you use namespaces in the api subfolder?